# Cannot Connect to Windows server 2012 IIS 7 after installing PHP for windows

Tags: php, windows, iis-7

OK, I added PHP 5.3 64BIT on Windows Server 2012 into IIS 7 through the download site: http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/documentation

So, it installed, had a few issues with PHP turning off some of my sites, but I quickly resolved that error.

Now, all my FTP connections or the only FTP connection to my 1and1 server is now DEAD.

What the heck happened?

I can't find for the life of me, where the FTP server config is on IIS or the Win2012 Server itself.

This needs to be fixed PRONTO!!!!!

Please help...

I'm getting critical ERROR using Filezilla and the standard blurb with Dreamweaver stating the obvious, "AN FTP ERROR OCCURRED - Cannot make connection to host... "

Thoughts and solutions, please!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Checked the firewall and ports?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine... bizarre

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP Manager changed the configuration of IIS, I located a solution online that explained, very simply, that I needed to create an Global FTP site for the entire package. Poof!!! It works like a charm. Tada!!!!!!!!!!

Thanks all...